# Experiencing GUI delays in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I use the Data Import Wizard (DIW) for file loading.  And lately, simply right clicking on a table and then selecting the DIW option to bring up the wizard, I experience a 1-2 minute lag before the GUI dialog box even comes up.  Furthermore, as I progress thru the steps of the DIW GUI, each step will delay 1-2 minutes before moving on to the next. So all together, using the DIW can typically take me > 10 min.

What could be causing this and how might I remedy the issue?

I'm using Oracle SQL Dev version: 18.4.0.376

Regards,
rhelm

Comment: ThatJeffSmith would be the right person to help you. Wait for sometime, he usually replies most questions with sqldeveloper tag.

Comment: By any chance you have network drives that are 'far away' mapped in your OS? that might explain the first delay, but not the subsequent ones. Have you tried grabbing version 19.4? It's a year and 4 updates newer than 18.4

Comment: I do have far away mapped drives but my co-workers do as well and do not have the issue.  Also, I believe we are all on the same version but I will need to confirm.  Tks, Jeff.

Comment: I believe I'm stuck at the current version for the time being based on corp req's.  I should add that the delay is present for any sql dev Wizard gui.  Might there be a setting or preference that could contribute to these delays?

Comment: Another clue: the "IndexPreferencesTask" always seems to be running in the bottom right of the window. And appears hung when trying to navigate a dialog box.  Can this be turned off/killed?  If so, where?

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to update to the current v19.2 and no longer experience any delays.